# Eclipse is crashing on launch; can't figure out why

Tags: eclipse

My copy of Eclipse (Mars.2) on Windows 10 stopped working this past Sunday for no obvious reason. Ever since then, when I try to launch Eclipse, I get a very brief glimpse of the splash screen, then it closes. There is no new log file in the eclipse\configuration folder; the oldest one is several days old. There was no exit code screen like the ones I've seen when I had exit code 13 or exit code 1. I've got a single JDK in C:\Program Files and it is the latest and greatest 64-bit JDK (at least the download link said it was a 64-bit version. I've forgotten how to determine with certainty what version it is via command line parameters.) I've tried installing newer versions of Eclipse, including both a version of Neon and the latest version of Oxygen, on both my C: drive and my F: drive (the other logical drive on my internal hard drive) and all of them have the same symptoms.

I've installed a copy of Netbeans 8.2 just to see if *it* would install and work and it seems to do fine. I was able to import projects from my Eclipse workspace and the various bits of code seemed to import fine. I also wrote a very basic HelloWorld just to see if it would run and it did. I *think* that means my JDK and my Eclipse workspace are fine. But Eclipse still won't launch. I'm completely baffled and can't think of what to do to make it work again. It was just fine right up until Sunday morning.

Logically, you have to be suspecting I did something silly right about then: messed with settings that I should have left alone, deleted something I shouldn't have deleted or something along those lines. I can't think of *anything* I did that in retrospect seems foolish. All I did was reboot Windows as I periodically do. Now, Eclipse resolutely refuses to work *and won't tell me why*.

I could just abandon Eclipse and move on to Netbeans or IntelliJ or one of the other IDEs but I've been using Eclipse happily for some time. I really don't want to invest the time it's going to take to learn how to do all the things I do in Eclipse in another IDE. How can I get it working again?

Comment: try running the eclipse.exe from a command line windows and include the -consolelog and -debug options.  Post what you get

Comment: When I cd into the eclipse directory in the command prompt window and execute: eclipse.exe -consolelog -debug with no arguments, I get a fleeting glimpse of the splash screen, then it disappears. No error message of any kind and no log file written to eclipse\configuration. Did you want me to add any arguments to -consolelog and/or -debug?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I solved this problem by uninstalling the sole JDK and JRE on the computer, then reinstalling them. I'm not sure what was messed up but that got my Eclipse working normally again.